# item buttons needs two clicks to launch new activity

Tags: android, button, android-actionbar

I have a main activity with an action bar with the classic "overflow" button and other item buttons at the top of the layout. The problem I have is that I need to click item buttons twice to launch the following activity. I don't want this to happen, I just want "one click" to launch an activity. Here is my code (sorry if I do not post correctly). How can I fix it? Thank you.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

//Aggiungere listener per tutti gli item! (estrarre i listener)
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            //TODO
            return true;
        case R.id.filters:
            item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FiltersActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        });
        return true;
        case R.id.action_new:
            return true;
        case R.id.add_button:
            item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ButtonsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        });
        return true;
        case R.id.add_project:
            //TODO
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

and the XML file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.logger.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

    <item 
        android:id="@+id/filters"
        android:title="@string/filter"
        android:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item 
        android:id="@+id/action_new"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
        android:visible="true"
        android:title="@string/action_new">

        <menu>

           <item 
               android:id="@+id/add_project"
               android:showAsAction="never"
               android:title="@string/add_project"/>

           <item 
               android:id="@+id/add_button"
               android:showAsAction="never"
               android:title="@string/add_button"/>

       </menu>

    </item>

</menu>
```

Comment: wat u want to do? click on `add_button` and then ur activty must launch?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `setOnMenuItemClickListener()`.

At this point in your code, the `MenuItem` has already been clicked.

- `onCreateOptionsMenu()` creates the menu
- `onOptionsItemSelected()` reacts the the `MenuItem` click

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to set the onClickListeners in the switch statement!
just put this for example

```
case R.id.add_button: {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ButtonsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from here :

```
item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ButtonsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
});
```

You are setting an `OnItemClickListener` inside an `OnOptionsItemSelected`. The process will be the following :

1. When your item is clicked : set the OnItemClickListener
2. When your item is clicked a second time : make the action written in the OnItemClickListener.

You should remove the OnItemClickListener from the OnOptionsItemSelected to make it works correctly.

PS : a Listener is an object waiting for an action. When you set one for the first time : it not executes right now ! It waits for the action that it listened to. So when you set your OnItemClickListener, you have to click the button for the action occures.